# Handling SQL Locks

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to think of an appropriate way to handle SQL record locks in .NET.  Please see the pseudo code below:

```
Create Serialized Transaction
UPDATE dbusns SET USN=-100 WHERE USN=100
UPDATE dbusns SET USN=100 WHERE URN=1 and dataset='Dataset1' 
UPDATE dbusns SET USN=100 WHERE URN=12 and dataset='Dataset2' 
UPDATE dbusns SET USN=100 WHERE URN=9 and dataset='Dataset1' 
UPDATE dbusns SET USN=100 WHERE URN=7 and dataset='Dataset1' 
commit
```

There are usually up to 100 records to update.  If a user searches for USN 100 after the serialized transaction is created and before it is committed then it will hang.

What is the best way of handling a hang like this? Do you just let the SQLConnection/SQLCommand timeout or do you somehow set a lock timeout and then display a helpful error message.

I notice that SQL has a locktimeout property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182729.aspx.  Is it worth using this in .NET?

Comment: Speed up your transaction.  Why not make 1 update?  Create a temp table with the values and join columns you need.  Then begin a transaction and a single update with a join to that temp table and set all the rows at one time and then commit.

Comment: Add BEGIN TRAN before first UPDATE and COMMIT TRAN at the end. Or start transaction in VB.net. Don't forget try-catch enclosure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do the reverse of what you are doing, then at the end, swap them all back to +100

```
Create Serialized Transaction
UPDATE dbusns SET USN = -100 WHERE USN=100
UPDATE dbusns SET USN = -100 WHERE URN=1 and dataset='Dataset1' 
UPDATE dbusns SET USN = -100 WHERE URN=12 and dataset='Dataset2' 
UPDATE dbusns SET USN = -100 WHERE URN=9 and dataset='Dataset1' 
UPDATE dbusns SET USN = -100 WHERE URN=7 and dataset='Dataset1' 

UPDATE dbusns SET USN=100 WHERE URN=100

commit
```

But I don't know the basis of your original changing 100 to -100.  You may need to edit your original question with clarification.

An additional option for locking is to add a timestamp/datetime column to the table and assign it a common "lastLocked" date-time for all entries you are working on.  Then, you can always clear if anyone does NOT unlock when finished after a given time period like 10, 20 minutes or so as needed.

Comment: Thanks, but the question was do you handle locks explicitly by telling the user that a record is locked and if so,  how?

Comment: @w0051977,  What do you mean by being "locked" as you are trying to update many records from different "URN" and "Dataset" values.  What is the CONTEXT of the system.  Even if not exposing private information, the GENERAL purpose to it.  Can you add a column to the "DBUSNS" table to help act as a locking mechanism?

Comment: thanks.  That is what I was thinking.  Add a row called "locked".  Then if a process has an exclusive lock (performing an update), then set the boolean to 1.  Set it to 0 on finishing.  Just worried about the overhead i.e. two SQL statements instead of one.  What do you think? +1 for comment.

Comment: @w0051977, either int, or a timestamp... reason being... if nobody "unlocks" it, you could go back and do an unlock on say... anything locked over 10, 20, 30 minutes or so.

Comment: Thanks.  Timestamp is the answer.  Please amend your answer and then I will mark it.

Comment: @w0051977, revised answer with timestamp context.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle this through proper error handling. As a rule, I only add error handling on user initiating events, not on every sub/function/property. This way the error will bubble back up to the user initiated event and stop all code at that point. This is the same place your connections and transactions should be maintained.

Then, you can add specific catch blocks for different exception types and handle them properly, in this case, you will get a [SQLException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx) that you can inspect and handle how you want.